# Duplicate field row TEXT to JSON in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to duplicate a **TEXT** field into a **JSON** field.

What I am trying is:

```
UPDATE `table` SET text_field = JSON_ARRAY(json_field);
```

Because without **JSON_ARRAY** it is throwing this error:

```
#3140 - Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value."
```

---

The problem is that I **already have the JSON Array in the TEXT field**, so that JSON from the text field:

```
[{"tagname":"TEST","category":"DEFAULT","isnew":"yes","isdeleted":"no"}]
```

is converted to the JSON FIELD like this:

```
["[{\"tagname\":\"TEST\",\"category\":\"DEFAULT\",\"isnew\":\"yes\",\"isdeleted\":\"no\"}]"]
```

I want that the JSON field has a JSON format like the TEXT field.

Comment: So, do you need just to insert the text string '[{"tagname":"TEST","category":"DEFAULT","isnew":"yes","isdeleted":"no"}]' into a text field?

Comment: No, I need to copy the text field into a JSON field.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your TEXT field into a JSON field? Just like explained here: https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-json-data-stored-in-text-columns/

Comment: I will check it, thank you for the info!

Comment: If "without JSON_ARRAY" is throwing in error, whatever you try to use as input just seems to not be a valid json string. Try `select cast('your string, e.g. your text field' as json);`. If it complains, find out why. It comes down to this problem. If you use `json_array` for a non-valid-json (so "just a string"), you just get an (escaped) string (as you did), it doesn't fix that it's invalid json. Your string looks valid, so it might be something else; add some examples and **the full error message** including "at position" for `select cast('...' as json)`, and your mysql version.

Comment: That falied too. I will try deeper in a near future. Jus researched for mysql info and I have given up. Too much documentation to learn and too much doubts to put them here at stackoverflow. I will keep working with php arrays and text fields. In a near future I will keep trying that JSON field, but first I need to study it a lot. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON_UNQUOTE to remove the \" that are escaping the fields.

Comment: Thankyou, but the biggest problem problem is that with JSON_ARRAY is creating another array in the json field.

Comment: Why are you not using JSON_ARRAY_APPEND or something like JSON_SET?

Comment: This one did not give me the results that I want. I say the same I said at the top: I will try deeper in a near future. Jus researched for mysql info and I have given up. Too much documentation to learn and too much doubts to put them here at stackoverflow. I will keep working with php arrays and text fields. In a near future I will keep trying that JSON field, but first I need to study it a lot. Thank you for the help.